# Cannot index with multidimensional key error

Tags: python

What does cannot index with multidimensional key mean?
Tried to change `avg_wins.ix` to `avg_wins.loc` but no luck.
How do I correct this issue?

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? What is the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is from `pandas` or `dask`. It pops up when you try to `.loc` (locate) from a `pd.DataFrame` or `dd.DataFrame`, which has a `MultiIndex` column.

Your output should look like this:

```
df.columns

MultiIndex([(           'A', 'first'),
            (           'B', 'first'),
            (           'C', 'mean')])
```

and so on. Otherwise it will simply output a flat list of columns.

So in a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html) you can do different things, but what helps is to know how you can `.loc` (locate/filter) pretty easy:

```
df['A','first']
```

will give you that column and

```
df.loc[df['A','first'] == 5]
```

let you filter over a `MultiIndex` column.

Dask: `MultIndex` is used as default in `dask` [`groupby`](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/02-groupby.html) functions, when using multiple aggregate functions for one column, like this:

```
my_aggregate = {
    'A': 'first',
    'B': 'first',
    'C': ['mean','last'],
```

TL;DR: Look for a pandas/dask `MultiIndex` column.